# What is a Dad move in RPGs?

Tags: terminology

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158459/how-can-i-meet-the-needs-of-players-in-a-party-whose-characters-have-opposite-al/158469) the asker writes

> They are both roughly my age, so I can't pull a 'Dad move' on the murder hobo.

A comment said

> You're never too old or young to pull a Dad move. As a DM you kind of have to step into that role sometimes.

In the context of the role-playing game hobby, what's a Dad move?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A "Dad Move" is a way for DMs to deal with problem players.

Let's say you are running a game with a kid playing.  He's your friend's son, and his dad is excited to share his hobby with his kid.

The thing is, this kid attempts to kill everyone, makes terrible choices on purpose, etc. You can't blame him—he's just a kid who wants to have some fun.  However, he's a pain in the neck as a DM and really sucking the enjoyment out of the game for the other players.

So, you pull him aside after one of your sessions. Putting on your best "Dad Voice" (or "Mom Voice") you explain to him that although he should enjoy himself, he needs to respect other players, etc.

To summarize, a "Dad Move" is treating him like you would your own kid, and kindly—but firmly—explaining that the player needs to stop their problematic behavior.

Comment: Leading with a general definition of the term then explaining how to apply the term to RPGs might make for a more comprehensive answer. (Also, citing a source or two for the definition would make the answer sharper.)

Comment: Hm. So no terrible puns, practical jokes, or unexpected dad noises? I need to reevaluate my DM'ing techniques.

Comment: TL:DR: taking advantage of your assumed authority / license to instruct on how to behave which comes from the age difference.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica You risk setting off other dads in a chain reaction actually.